# 自動で画像を外部スクリーンにフルスクリーンで表示するには

Tags: opencv, qt, qt-creator

Qt CreatorでC++で開発をしています．
プロジェクションマッピング用の画像をQtで作成後すぐに接続したプロジェクタで投影したいのですが，自動化の方法が分かりません．作業用のデスクトップと投影用のデスクトップを分けたいので今は画像ウィンドウを作業用デスクトップに表示し，画面の右にドラッグして外部スクリーン上で最大化しています．

```py
import tkinter as tk
import cv2
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import pyautogui as pag

scr_w,scr_h= pag.size()

root = tk.Tk()
w = scr_w # 横の長さ
h = scr_h # 縦の長さ
x = scr_w # 座標軸x
y = 0 # 座標軸y

root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w,h, x, y))

result = cv2.imread("/Users/hoge/Desktop/result_pmi.png")
height, width, ch = result.shape
rgb_cv2_image = cv2.resize(result, dsize=(int(h/height*width),scr_h))
rgb_cv2_image = cv2.cvtColor(rgb_cv2_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

pil_image = Image.fromarray(rgb_cv2_image)
tk_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pil_image)

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, bg="white", height=h, width=w)
canvas.create_image((w-int(h/height*width))/2, 0, image=tk_image, anchor=tk.NW)
canvas.place(x=0, y=0)
root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
root.mainloop()
```

このpythonプログラムを
`std::system("/opt/anaconda3/bin/python ./test.py")`
で呼び出します

ここまでで外部スクリーンに表示することはできたのですが，scr_w,scr_h= pag.size()が得るのは外部スクリーンのサイズではなく作業用デスクトップのサイズなので外部スクリーン上で画面いっぱいに画像を表示することができません．

Comment: もしかして該当のPythonスクリプトの開発を`venv`や`Anacondaのconda`等で専用環境を作成して行っていて、基本の環境とはインストールされているモジュールが違うのでは？ そしてC++から単に外部プログラム起動すると基本の環境のPythonが呼ばれるとか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございますsystem("/opt/anaconda3/bin/python ./test.py")と，pythonをフルパスで指定することで実行の問題は解決しました

Comment: こんな記事とモジュールがあるようなので試してみてはどうでしょう？[How to detect multiple screens](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62606226/9014308), [rr-/screeninfo](https://github.com/rr-/screeninfo), [How to make a window fullscreen in a secondary display with tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26286660/9014308)

Comment: ありがとうございます．screeninfoで解決しました

Answer (score 1):

screeninfoでマルチモニターのサイズを取得し，画像サイズをフルスクリーンに適応させることができました

```py
import tkinter as tk
import cv2
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import pyautogui as pag
import screeninfo
import re
import sys


m = screeninfo.get_monitors()
print(m)
m = str(m)
scr_w = re.findall("width=\d+",m)
scr_h = re.findall("height=\d+",m)
scr_w = re.findall("\d+",scr_w[1])
scr_h = re.findall("\d+",scr_h[1])

scr_w,scr_h = int(scr_w[0]),int(scr_h[0])

root = tk.Tk()
def close(event): #escキーで閉じる
    root.withdraw() # if you want to bring it back
    sys.exit() # if you want to exit the entire thing

root.bind('<Escape>', close)
w = scr_w # 横の長さ
h = scr_h # 縦の長さ
x = scr_w # 座標軸x
y = 0 # 座標軸y

root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))

result = cv2.imread("/Users/hoge/Desktop/result_pmi.png")
height, width, ch = result.shape
rgb_cv2_image = cv2.resize(result, dsize=(int(h/height*width),scr_h))
rgb_cv2_image = cv2.cvtColor(rgb_cv2_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

pil_image = Image.fromarray(rgb_cv2_image)
tk_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pil_image)

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, bg="black", height=h, width=w)
canvas.create_image((w-int(h/height*width))/2, 0, image=tk_image, anchor=tk.NW)
canvas.place(x=0, y=0)
root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
root.mainloop()
```